# Need to change my DNS

Tags: dns, subdomain

Actually, I bought two domains **www.example.com** and **www.example.info**

- *www.example.com* is used for hosted my website in aws
- *www.example.info* is used for a blog and it hosted in godaddy

I planned to maintain a only one domain so what move from **www.example.info** to **www.exampe.com/xyz/**.(blog is moves to sub domain of www.example.com)

Answer (score 0):

need more clarity on your question. if you want to move your blog to sub domain of your example.com. blog link will be www.blog.example.com. you can not move www.example.ifo DNS to blog.example.com. DNS record changes only applies to Main Domain.

Comment: yeah it fine www.blog.exampe.com suppose it feasible

Comment: If apache is  your webserver, move your entire blog folder to /var/www/html/ and create database schema in your database server. now you can visit blog website in www.example.com/blogname or you can create subdomain as www.blog.example.com pointing to /blogdirectory name(subdomain option in cpanel).